# How to attach database file in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I am trying to attach a SQL Server database file in Visual Studio but with no luck, I'm stuck with a message that says:

> Cannot open user default database. Login failed.

I even try to take the database offline, copied it into the project folder that I'm working on but still, nothing happens. Any help will gladly be appreciated...

Comment: How are you trying to attach a database file to Visual Studio?

Comment: I am browsing it to the drive that I save on. But I already solved my problem with regards to that, Akshara. Thanks for asking..